# How to use ktap on android device?

Tags: android, linux-kernel

Has anyone successfully use ktap on android device? 
ktap is scripting dynamic tracing tool for Linux, hosted on https://github.com/ktap/ktap.

Comment: From the ktap project readme, it supports x86, arm, ppc, mips, but don't have any clue to make it work on android platform, any suggestions is much appreciated.